# Regular expression for pepper+tomato+watermelon

Tags: regex

Regular expression for something+something+something ... +something?

Sorry because of my great english and brain -> keyboard connection

Comment: Are you saying you want to be able to parse expressions with + signs?
Meaning:
A+B+1.2345+apple+sandwich+banana+(9)?

Or do you only want numbers? Or letters? Or do you literally want to detect "something+something+something"?

Comment: letters a-z with + sign between, number of + signs must be smaller then number of words

example-> pepper+tomato+watermelon

Comment: Pepper, tomato and watermelon?  What on earth are you cooking!!

Comment: @jonnii - perhaps a salad? http://find.myrecipes.com/recipes/recipefinder.dyn?action=displayRecipe&recipe_id=1823321 :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/\w+(\s*\w+)*(\+\w+(\s*\w+)*)*/
```

This should also match phrases of multiple words, if you need that.  It also matches non-alpha characters, but you can replace \w with [a-z] if you explicitly want to exclude everything but letters. Just make sure you specify the regex to be case insensitive if you expect capital letters.

edit: commenter below noticed I didn't have the plus sign after the \w 's, so it was only matching a single character at a time. \w+ will match entire words, with an optional space in between, which was the original intention. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: you have the lowest reputation of the people present so

Comment: Well, I'm not too worried about my rep. You should pick the answer that best meets the needs of your problem, but if that's me then great.

Comment: I'm not sure what Doug is attempting to do here? Replacing \w(\s*\w)* with \w+( \w+)* would be a better way to match phrases, if that is desired. Otherwise the whole expression should just be \w+(\+\w+)*

Answer (score 11):

```
([a-zA-Z]+(\+[a-zA-Z]+)*)
```

Comment: i'm still not sure if this is what the OP really wanted, but I've gotten a good laugh out of this nevertheless :)

Answer (score 2):

If the "something" is always a word and needs at least two entries

```
\w(\+\w)+
```

or for any repeating sequence

```
\w(\+\w)*
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment clarifying the question, here's an updated answer:

```
([a-z]+\+)*[a-z]+
```

or

```
[a-z]+(\+[a-z]+)*
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to escape the '+' and the '.' as they are reserved.

For example, in ruby:

```
/something\+something\+something \.\.\. \+something/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the `+` metacharacter using `\+` in your regular expression, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, would a string split method work?

```
"Or+Something+like+that".split('+')
```